# Error installing mssql-tools with brew on Mac OS

Tags: sql-server

I get this error when I try installing the tools

```
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
* microsoft/mssql-preview/mssql-tools
* microsoft/mssql-release/mssql-tools
```

Answer (score 22):

This error is triggered if you previously tapped the preview repo. You can resolve this by the following commands

```
brew untap microsoft mssql-preview
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install mssql-tools
```

Comment: I had a similar issue that this pattern helped fix. My error was with multiple taps for microsoft/msodbcsql/msodbcsql and microsoft/mssql-reelase/msodbcsql. I used this answer and ran untap for both, then tap/update/install as you have it listed. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 2):

The fix above didn't help me.
What did, is to specify the full name of the package on the brew install section.

A.K.A -

```
brew untap microsoft mssql-preview 
<if this tap does not exist, then> -
brew untap microsoft mssql-release
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release 
https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install microsoft/mssql-release/mssql-tools
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem